# Copy MySQL user to create a new one

Tags: mysql

I have a ton of users on many different MySQL servers with this type

```
myuser@localhost
myotheruser@localhost
```

now, I want to create new users, that should have the same password as the user above, and have access to the same databases, but from a different host like this:

```
myuser@127.0.0.1
myotheruser@127.0.0.1
```

does anyone have a quick and easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried a different approach to this problem, but running these two commands:

```
mysqldump --skip-extended-insert mysql user | grep 'localhost' | egrep '^INSERT INTO' | sed 's/localhost/127.0.0.1/g' > add-local-ip-user.sql

mysqldump --skip-extended-insert mysql db | grep 'localhost' | egrep '^INSERT INTO' | sed 's/localhost/127.0.0.1/g' > add-local-ip-db.sql
```

Then, I just output the content:

```
cat add-local-ip*
```

then I open mysql:

```
mysql mysql
```

and finally just paste the output from above, and run `flush privileges` does anyone have any objection to doing it this way? e.g. is this a stupid solution?